# What's its Header file of PF_PACKET and ETH_P_ALL in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, macos, sockets

The header files of macro of `PF_PACKET` and `ETH_P_ALL` in C in Xcode. I am using `socket` with `SOCK_RAW`; There're two macros I don't know what is the header files? Need Help.

Comment: I would try the following in a bash: `find /usr/include -name "*.h" -exec grep -n 'PF_PACKET' {} /dev/null \;`. (I do not know anything about  Xcode. Thus it might be that `/usr/include` has to be replaced by the correct directory.)

Comment: I've tried to find the name of 'PF_PACKET', but nothing was found. Still Thanks. @Scheff

Comment: I did what I recommended: googling for "PF_PACKET OSX". I learnt that low-level network things are a little bit different on BSD (and thus on OSX). Look at [Using FreeBSD's BPF device with C/C++](http://bastian.rieck.ru/howtos/bpf/) or google for "BPF_PACKET OSX".

Comment: _I did what I recommended: googling for "PF_PACKET OSX"._ Oops. Actually, I didn't recommend it before (though I could/should have). However, glad if I could help (considering that _I do not know anything about Xcode._) ;-)

Comment: You're right. Later on I found that `PF_PACKET ` and `ETH_P_ALL` are options in a certain C file in Linux OS, so it has a little bit difference in MAC OS. But it has a difficult implementation on macOS, I gave up.  Thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<sys/socket.h>    

#include<linux/if_packet.h>

#include<net/ethernet.h>
```

Include these header files. It worked for me.